# Can our universe be a pocket in a bigger unseen eternal universe?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, cosmology

Taking time as a fourth dimension is due to Einstein because of the speed of light being fixed. But why should such a finding have so important consequence on our philosophical contemplation of existence? I think philosophical questions are generally deeper than such scientific contingencies.

Let me explain my point: Suppose that we came to discover a new mean of communication other than light, and suppose we can detect it and make calculations about it by our devices, much as we do of light, etc... Suppose that this physical object travels at a very imaginary speed, like for example can traverse the whole width of our universe is a negligible fraction of a nanosecond. Would that brings us back to the older model of having absolute space and time? by then we can map all of what is existing NOW in the universe, which would be a very different map from what we are seeing depending on light.

On the other hand, if we depend on light for our information, then light having a fixed speed, would raise doubt of deficient information! Let me explain: for example what our devices are detecting is what *reached* us of electromagnetic radiation from the parts of the universe that are so near to us as to make this reach possible. But there still can be the case that there are some parts of the universe like stars light from which didn't yet reach us! Accordingly what we are seeing like the big bang, the expanding universe, etc.., could be just a pocket of the universe that is within our reach, and it might be just a small territory in a vastly bigger universe that we cannot visualize because light from it didn't reach us yet. I mean the domain of *place* and *time* would be bigger than the observed universe. Is there a scientific argument that falsifies the existence of such external universe? that could even be eternal? having fixed rules, in which change only occurs on matters inside it (like our observed universe).

My question is: is the observed information that science is speaking about the universe enough to settle old philosophical questions about eternity or non-eternity of existence as a whole? Or should metaphysics settle such a question?

Comment: The problem with humans.. is.that they can imagine things that don't exist.. like infinity.. or pink unicorns that fart rainbows. Science... was foundered to determine what is real and what is not. It turns out.. that a lot of things we can imagine are real problems in metaphysics... are simply the secular equivelent of asking how many angels.can dance on the head of a pin.

Comment: @Richard, yes you might be right, but here the question why should we believe that what we are seeing is necessarily the whole picture? it might not, especially speech about an expanding space-time complex, this seems to be incoherent, if space itself is expanding, its expanding where, in ordinary life we describe expansion of objects and we need those objects to be in space to expand, same to be said of having a beginning this is of events but there is time before them, the usual description of scientists seems to imply that both there is a space beyond space and time before and after time?

Comment: No observed information can settle philosophical questions, and metaphysics has been unable to settle any questions since its inception, as already Kant pointed out. Our universe "could be" anything, we could all be stuck in a Matrix, or fooled by an evil demon. Such questions are idle and unanswerable without some specific context for handling them, we generally try to avoid entertaining pure speculations on this site.

Comment: There's something a bit off in this question relating to how exactly you're critiquing `c` and the BB.  `c` in relativity doesn't really have to do with light per se; it has to do with space-time itself.  Likewise, the BB doesn't as is commonly suggested say that the universe had a beginning, or that what we see is all there is; rather, it simply projects that all of the observable universe we do see was concentrated at a point ~14BYA, at which point in time none of our current models can say anything (that's the "singularity").

Comment: @HWalters, the main point is that the universe is not eternal by this BB model. It appears to be a scientific fact much as the earth is not flat. However it is really difficult to understand what does it mean to say that time-space complex itself is expanding? Anyhow

Comment: Cosmology faq on [what happened before big bang](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmology_faq.html#BBB); also consider specifically [eternal inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation).  On the size of the universe, [back to the cosmology faq](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/infpoint.html).

Comment: @Zuhair the more we learn about the nsture of reality the more we realise that the senses nature provided us are inadequate for comprehending it. Our eyesight is very narrow for example.. If we could see radio waves out perception might be different. Science gives us better eyes. To answer directly.. the usual answer is to imagine drawing dots equally.spaced on a baloon.. then inflate it. Each dot moves away from the next. Now try and imagine that in 3 dimensions. As to what its expanding into.. When you pile 2d sheets of paper.. into what do you pile them?

Comment: @Zuhair actually i think i just needlessly invented a dimension to allow for expansion. Disregard my answer for rhat.. space is a manifestation of our universe.. there need not be any space outside it to expand into.

Comment: @Richard, i still think it is something very hard to imagine really. When one says *expanding* usually it is meant to be an *object* expanding *in* space. That space itself is expanding!? this is very strange, since space it not an object for it to expand in the in the first place, and expand into where? into another space? into nowhere? The examples you've given are clearly about an object in space. So it is hardly an analogy

Comment: @Zuhair think of space as being elastic. Its not that space is being 'created' its that its stretching. asking into what makes no sense. Swap the word 'space' for 'orange'. Imagine an orange in the middle of a barrel of apples.. now.. the orange inhabitants of the orange can imagine only oranges and things which are orange.the ask, into what orange is our orange, becoming more orange.

Comment: @Richard, space being elastic?! what's that? being elastic is a property of objects, how can something like space be elastic. Space is not an object.

Comment: @Zuhair exactly what space *is* nobody knows. But whatever it is.. it's stretching.

Comment: It's odd how Conifold says that metaphysics has been unable to settle any questions since its inception, and Richard says nobody knows what space is. It's as if there is a wall around the Academy shutting out most of philosophy. The question seems to be scientific to me, since it makes no difference to metaphysics whether there is one or a million 'pockets'. In the end there is just one Reality.

Comment: Taking time as a fourth dimension due to Fakestein is something entirely useless. Time is a static, constant concept, nothing more. Observations are a very long story because you cannot measure a change in something if the device you measure with is affected by the same things your observable objective is.

Comment: @Zuhair What we see today is already not the whole picture of what exists, every second there are around 50 thousand stars disappearing from view (of today's telescopes) , so we know there is more 'universe' out there, but is it infinite, none knows.

Comment: @PeterJ to be fair.. metaphysics doesn't know either.

Comment: @Conifold, yes to some extend I'd agree, but then why scientists are presenting their theories in nearly absolute tone? for example many times they emphasize that when they say the "universe", it refers to ALL of what's there! If observed data is always insufficient, then this statement must not be made. By the way the speculation that I've spoken about here is not one without any connection to observed date like the examples you've gave, so they are not on a par. Actually the usual wording (which might be mis-wording) of the BB, is misleading, and gives impression of external existence.

Comment: People present all sorts of outlandish things in a categorical tone all the time (see TV and internet), at least in science one can find caveats and qualifications in professional publications. Stuffing them into loose public statements is beyond impractical, so one shouldn't take any precise "impressions" from them. And this is not specific to science: if we try to make the proper context explicit whenever we want to say something we will end up never saying a word.

Comment: @Zuhair most cosmologists do talk about the 'observable' universe. That the unobservable universe is contiguous, is extrapolated from what we know about what we can see. The fact that we're around at a time we can still see creation is another example of 'goldilocks' providence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe metaphysics should answer this question, because big philosophical questions still seem to be argued even *after* science proves them unreal. This is my simple answer.

Comment: If you have any references this would support your answer and give the reader a place to go for more information. In particular, what has science proved unreal that people continue to argue? I agree with you, but I am looking for a way to strengthen your answer.

Comment: It is not a metaphysical question. Metaphysics assumes one Universe and one Reality. If it has an infinity of 'pockets' this makes no difference.

Comment: @Frank Hubeny me too. I remember having *seen* arguments science proved unreal that people continue to argue, but right now none of them come to mind...How about certain aspects of all religions?